# CWiiD doesn't detect wii remote but hcitool and blueman do

Tags: raspbian, python, bluetooth

I have a raspberry pi 2 model B version 1 running raspbian that I am trying to get a Wii remote to work with. I have an Inateck Bluetooth 4.0 adapter plugged in to it and have [CWiiD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CWiiD) installed. When I type hcitool scan and push 1 + 2 on Wii remote the output is

```
Scanning ...
    58:BD:A3:C4:9E:7C   Nintendo RVL-CNT-01-TR
```

However, when I go to python 2.7.9 and run [this code](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/robo-butler/code/wii_remote_1.py) it always outputs

```
Press 1 + 2 on your Wii Remote now ...
No wiimotes found
Error opening wiimote connection
```

(The "No wiimotes found" only show up when I run the code with `sudo python wii_remote_1.py` instead of just `python wii_remote_1.py`)

Please tell me if you know how to fix this.

Comment: What OS (Raspian etc. are you using) - that CWiiD package comes from the Ubuntu site, so perhaps you mean the packages [here](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/c/cwiid/).  The message about "No Wiimotes found" means that the library is operable (the failure unless using sudo means there is a permissions problem with the normal user that you are, "pi" perhaps, with the device that represents the hardware concerned.  Given this is a Bluetooth device I wonder whether the RPis Bluetooth system is not (yet) paired with the Wiimote device...

Comment: CWiiD has been rumored to only work with the Nintendo brand Wiimotes, make sure you don't have a knock off one.

Comment: Right now I am using raspbian and I am using a wii remote that has the nintendo and wii logo, so I assume is the official remote.

Comment: I have 2 knock off ones - I ended up using the 2 that came with the Wii

Comment: New wiimote batteries fixed it for me!

Comment: I have same issue and am finding the cwiid library doesn't support the wii remote plus. More background [here](https://github.com/rektide/cwiid/issues/1) and [here](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote). I'm trying another previous rev remote & will update if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. Heres what I did. I do not know what actually made it work, but it is working.

1. Used different Wii remote
2. Turned off Wii
3. Re-Installed Raspbian (Saved all important files on usb so they wouldn' be erased)
4. Downloaded and installed bluetooth and cwiid

I think that the Wii remote was trying to connect with the Wii and messing up the raspberry pi, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.